# Show/Hide Column in a Spreadsheet-converted-to-HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

I know that there are already a few answers regarding this subject, but I wanted to ask again, so that you can suggest the best option.

I have created a book that teaches (4 languages so far) at the same time. I will be selling various versions of this books travelling in Mexico. But it is also available online, free of charge. You can go directly to the version in question by visiting 
http://jersllvs.majormigraine.com

I have created this book using the spreadsheet program in the OpenOffice suite (same as excel). Right now there are 4 columns for the 4 languages and as I am starting to work on language #5, I am realizing that I can save myself a lot of work, if I can hide/show the columns on the page. What I want to do is use the spreadsheet program to create the `index.html` for this book with all languages, and then add the needed code to the html file so that the user can check/uncheck the languages. There will be a list of languages at the top of the screen (English, Spanish, etc.) and each language will consist of 3 columns which will extend the entire length of the page.

I only have a limited knowledge of basic HTML, but have a long history working with computers, and can learn whatever is needed. However, as this entire project is to remain completely free (and I still have to get out and sell books to make a living), I want to find the easiest and fastest way to achieve this.

Thank You very much for your answer,
Jerry

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use Jquery.  However this could be pretty complicated if you arent too familiary with it.  If you click the link I have provided below there is a short demonstration of what I think you are looking for.  However because your webpage is so big, I think it could be very complicated for you as there is a lot of styling involved as well.
Take a look at the link I have made, and see if thats what you want.  If yes, then you can slowly start to work out how to implement that into your site.  To make Jquery work on your webpage you need to add the following code into the `<head>` tag of your HTML page.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

and then the Jquery code that you may use from my link will need to be within the `<script>` tags which will look like

```
<script type="text/javascript">YOUR CODE HERE</script>
```

I hope this is what your looking for.  Here is the link to the page I have made for you: 
 http://jsfiddle.net/3xR2p/1/

Comment: Thank You for the answer.I will check it all out and try to implement the change this week.

Comment: It looks like I am going to have to learn a bit before I can really get started with this, but I did want to ask: Per the code in the HTML box that you provided, it looks like I will need to add a "class=" to each row. If this is true, then it will be more difficult than I was hoping. Currently, the page includes 12 columns and over 1300 rows... And this will all increase with time. I will stick with the simple HTML that I am using for now, and try and learn some Java and CSS over the next year. Thanks again for your help.